# cin.gcount() and its applications

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code

```
#include< iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
 char a[30];  
 cin.read(a,10);  
 cout<<(cin.gcount());  
  system("pause");  
  return 0;     
}
```

the output was 10 as expected....but then i wrote the following code

```
#include< iostream>    
using namespace std;   
int main()    
{    
 char a[30];    
 cin>>a;   
 cout<<(cin.gcount());    
  system("pause");    
  return 0;       
}
```

I entered "hello" which got stored in a.... the output this time was 0 instead of 5...if cin.gcount() returns the number of bytes read in last input operation, why this difference

Answer (score 5):

```
Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input 
operation performed on the object.

The unformatted input operations that modify the value returned by 
this function are those performed by the following member functions: 
get, getline, ignore, peek, read, readsome, putback and unget.
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Notice though, that peek, putback and unget do not extract characters. 
So gcount will always return zero after a call to any of these.
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/

`std::cin` is *not* unformatted input.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because [gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/) is only for ***unformatted*** reads. The [operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) is a formatted reader, [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) is not.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the cin.gcount() only works if preceeded by get() getline() or read() command.....
so it wont work the way you are trying to....
for reference...
http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200109/notes/io.html

Comment: The other three commands i.e., get() getline() read all store the input in a buffer which gcount uses to get the count of the input characters.......